# how NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update really works with Spring and MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, transactions, jdbctemplate

Ok, I've probably dug up the entire Google land and still couldn't find anything that could possibly answer my question.

I have my little foo method that does some deleting like this:

```
private void foo()
{
   jdbcNamedParameterTemplate.update(sqlString, params);   //1
   jdbcNamedParameterTemplate.update(sqlString2, params2); //2
}
```

sqlString and sqlString2 are just delete statements like "Delete * from FooBar".
So when I get to the second call to `update`, do I have any guarantee that whatever operation the first one invokes in the database has already finished?

Comment: when did you commit your transaction?

Comment: After BOTH update calls

Answer (score 0):

If you do that two in one session, and non multithreading, then yes the first one invokes in the database has already finished before the second update.

But if not in the same session you can check the version to check if the object already changed or not

```
int oldVersion = foo.getVersion();
session.load( foo, foo.getKey() ); // load the current state
if ( oldVersion != foo.getVersion()) { .... }// if true then the object has been changed
```